# external redirection in AngularJS erasing navigation stack

Tags: angularjs, navigation, angular-ui-router

We have set up different applications something like micro frontends running in different versions of Angular, one of them which is in AngularJS is required to redirect to a url which is in another project. Everything works until you try to go back using the browsers back button, and it takes you to the previous domain the user has navigated to. It can't go back to the immediately previous URL. It seems the navigation has been replaced but I can't see anything on the project that uses `location.replace`.

for example:

I am navigating

```
www.anyurl.com
```

then i go to my projects dns like

```
myproject.com/employer/dashboard
```

after I can click on to desired button which will take me to

```
myproject.com/employer/job-flow#location
```

Up to there everything is fine, but If I click on the browsers back button instead of taking me to:

```
myproject.com/employer/dashboard
```

It will go to the previous domain:

```
www.anyurl.com
```

I hope this is a clear explanation

from here: `/employer/search` to `/employer/job-flow#location`

The Process:

Declare a new item in the menu:

```
..., {
      title: 'Post a job',
      mainPath: 'job-flow',
      fallbackUrl: 'employer/job-flow',
      image: '/assets/images/new-job.svg',
      notification: false,
      subitems: [],
      enabled: true
    }
```

In the HTML there is a:

```
ng-href="{{ item.fallbackUrl }}"
```

Then there is an angular module which stores an array with all the routes:

```
var employerWebRoutes = [
  ...
  'employer/job-flow'
];
```

Afterwards the array is iterated (I think it works like an interceptor for the given routes):

```
employerWebRoutes.forEach( function ( route ) {
  $stateRegistryProvider.register( {
    url: '/' + route + '{path:.*}',
    name: route + 'ExternalState',
    component: 'merlExternalRoutesComponent',
    resolve: {
      reloadFromServer: reloadFromServerResolver
    },
    data: {
      authAccess: 'private',
      isExternalRoute: true
    }
  } );
} );
```

And lastly the reloadFromServerResolver method

```
var reloadFromServerResolver = [
  '$transition$',
  '$q',
  function (
    $transition$,
    /** angular.IQService */ $q
  ) {
    var /** @type module:angular.ui.IStateService */ stateService = $transition$.router.stateService;
    var /** @type string */ toUrl = stateService.href( $transition$.to().name, $transition$.params() );
    setTimeout( function () {
      window.location.assign( toUrl );
    }, 10 );
    return $q.reject();
  }
];
```

I am guessing this is how is done, I am new to this project and can't figure very well how to describe this problem, if anyone can point in the right direction I would be highly grateful. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "It can't go back to the immediately previous URL"? What does it do? Is there an error message in the Developer Console?

Comment: @georgeawg Please see the updated question.